# nativescript iOS app publishing issue with cocoapods frameworks

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript

I am trying to publish my nativescript app to itunes connect and am getting this error every time. I've tried publishing through xcode, app launcher & nativescript-cli.

[iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Bolts' is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnS7D.png)

This is a 3rd party library, not my app, so the bundle id for my app is not the issue.

I've tried using a wildcard profile and changing the bolts bundle to match my app bundle.

I've tried turning frameworks off in the podfile

I've tried the script that strips the required signing in post install.
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4331

Nothing seems to work. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put the text of the error in the question instead of linking to an image.

Comment: @fiveclubs done. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving by recreating the wildcard provisioning profile and then changing the bundle id to com.mycompany.app.Bolts in xcode and the project builds successfully.

this is not perfect however, since you can't use things like in app purchases with a wildcard so hopefully it gets resolved in the future.